# How does woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link filter hook work in depth?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I have some basic Woocommerce questions and cannot find anywhere online.

- from the code below, where are $args come from?
- how $product and $args assign to %s ?

thanks!

```php
global $product;

echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', // WPCS: XSS ok.
    sprintf( '<a href="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="%s" %s>%s</a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $args['quantity'] ) ? $args['quantity'] : 1 ),
        esc_attr( isset( $args['class'] ) ? $args['class'] : 'button' ),
        isset( $args['attributes'] ) ? wc_implode_html_attributes( $args['attributes'] ) : '',
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    ),
$product, $args );
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**1) Explanations for $args variable in template file `loop/add_to_cart.php`:**

The code in your question come from the template file [`loop/add_to_cart.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.6.0/templates/loop/add-to-cart.php).
It is called by [`content-product.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.6.0/templates/content-product.php) template file on [`woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.6.0/templates/content-product.php#L65) hook:

```
/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close - 5
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );
```

As you can see the template function [`woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.2/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L1346-L1385) does this job and it is located in WooCommerce plugin under `includes/wc-template-functions.php`.

So the default arguments are:

```
$defaults = array(
    'quantity'   => 1,
    'class'      => implode(
        ' ',
        array_filter(
            array(
                'button',
                wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ), // escaped in the template.
                'product_type_' . $product->get_type(),
                $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
                $product->supports( 'ajax_add_to_cart' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'ajax_add_to_cart' : '',
            )
        )
    ),
    'attributes' => array(
        'data-product_id'  => $product->get_id(),
        'data-product_sku' => $product->get_sku(),
        'aria-label'       => $product->add_to_cart_description(),
        'aria-describedby' => $product->add_to_cart_aria_describedby(),
        'rel'              => 'nofollow',
    ),
);
```

They are parsed through the filter hook `woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_args`:

```
$args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_args', wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults ), $product );
```

… allowing to make changes on this arguments.

> The **`$args` variable** in `woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link` is made of that.

---

2. **How `$product` and `$args` are assigned to `%s`**:

This is specific to PHP `printf()` and `sprintf()` function **where each `%s` are a placeholder**.

In `'<a href="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="%s" %s>%s</a>'`:

- the 1st placeholder `%s` will be replaced by `esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() )`
- the 2nd placeholder `%s` by `esc_attr( isset( $args['quantity'] ) ? $args['quantity'] : 1 )`
- `and so on…`

Documentation for [`printf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) and [`sprintf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) php functions.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I don't see where esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) get passed and for ...class="%s" %s>%s</a>, the first %s is class array and then attribute array, where is the last %s come from? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Loic! I was looking for this too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my way of actually changing the $args:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_args', 'filter_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_args', 10, 2 );
function filter_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_args( $args, $product ) {
    $args['quantity'] = 6;
    return $args;
}
```