# Changing the HTML of the add to cart button in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have this piece of code which I use for my checkout/order button. Which is pretty convenient, I can style the button and add custom text and classes. I know this won't work with translated content but that is of no importance here because the website is and will stay in only 1 language.

```
// Filter for adding extra custom line to order button
add_filter('woocommerce_order_button_html', 'mbm_custom_button_html');

function mbm_custom_button_html($button_html)
{

$button_html = '<button type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order">Lidmaatschap starten<br /><span class="extra-text-checkout-button">Betaal pas na gratis proefperiode</span></button>';

return $button_html;
}
```

I was wondering can I also use the same method for the add to cart button? But then something like `add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_button_html', 'mbm_custom_atc_button_html');` 
I tried to search it in the docs but could not find my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For "Add to Cart" part, you may try this hooks: `woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link` and `woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text`.

I believe, the first one provides a better solution for you. You may check the detailed usage via: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56179393/11003615 and http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link/

Hope those helps. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

for loop page

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 100);
```

for product single page

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 100);

function custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text(){
    return 'Add to catd 111';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There does not exists filter to change the 'ADD TO CART' button HTML.
If you need to do changes in HTML of 'ADD TO CART' button, you need to override the templates from plugin to your theme.

For example, for simple product 'ADD TO CART' button HTML, you need to override `/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php` to `/theme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php` and do changes in simple.php which is in a theme folder.

Answer (score -1):

Add below code in your active theme's function.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_button_html', 'ro_custom_cart_button_html' );

function ro_custom_cart_button_html( $button_html ) {
    $order_button_text = 'Submit';
    //add your html below where there is button tag
    $button_html = '<button type="submit" class="button alt" 
    name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="' . esc_attr( 
    $order_button_text ) . '" data-value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '">' . 
    esc_html( $order_button_text ) . '</button>';
    $button_html = str_replace( 'Place order', 'Submit', $button_html );
    return $button_html;
}
```

Tested and works well

Comment: This was not my question.. The code that I have is already working